# WP7: Render a video from image sequence

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, video, rendering

I am currently developing a Windows Phone 7 application. What I want to do, is to render a video file (avi, wmv, whatever...) from a sequence of images. So, I just need something like a frame writer for video files (e.g. create an in-game video: write every X frame to video stream).

I searched the whole internet and also stackoverflow but I didn't find anything. As far as I know, there are a lot of APIs and interfaces in the Windows Phone 7 stack to handle audio and video, so I think there must be a solution for this somehow.

BTW: I alread had a look at C# Slicer and ffmpeg. Slicer isn't available for Windows Phone 7 and I wasn't able to port it and ffmpeg isn't allowed by Microsoft, because this solution would need to integrate an unmanaged library which isn't allowed.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider doing this operation on a server? You could upload the images to your host, invoke ffmpeg to create the movie, then push the movie back to the phone. It might even be faster than having the phone do the encoding (assuming you don't have thousands of users hitting the host at the same time, of course!)

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. The app should also be able to run offline. And, by the way: I think uploading a bunch of images using the mobile data connection will also take it's time. I don't know if server side compression is really faster, but I asume it wouldn't be much faster.